# Why does Google Chrome only displays the first page a pdf file?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I'm facing a problem with Google Chrome. One of my PDF only shows the first page and the rest looks as following:

**Example:**

[image]
*First page is displayed normaly.*

[image]

*It recognizes the amount of pages in the PDF.*

If I download the PDF, it is completely fine and useable, I even can open it in Chrome and it works fine. The problem doesn't occur on Firefox or Safari.

I'm using Google Chrome Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue (but with another website). After investigation, it appears that this has something to do with SameSite cookies.

You can fix it by setting this flag to Disabled then restart Chrome:

```
chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies
```

Update: Found an issue in the Chromium bug tracker related to this problem:

```
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=961617
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be caused by a conflict between Chrome and Fast Web View pdf optimisation. To fix it you need to turn off the optimisation within your pdf program settings and save the file again (in Adobe products this is located Preferences>Documents>Save Settings - uncheck Save As optimizes for Fast Web View). Pdf files which don't include this optimisation render all pages correctly.

Comment: Probably Chrome actually wants to use that optimization. This in turn requires that the web server supports range requests. Could it be that your web server claims to support range requests but actually does not?